# laravel pagination not working with search

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have this code in my controller

```
  if (request('tag')) {
            $Posts = Tags::where('name' ,request('tag'))->firstOrFail()->Posts;
        } else {
            $Posts = Blog::paginate(10);
        }
        return view('Panel.Posts',['Posts' => $Posts]);
```

and this is my model function

```
public function tag(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tags::class,'Post_tag','Post_id');
    }
```

It's a web application I am creating and it's a blog.
I'm trying to create a category.
I want to paginate my search method but I can't do it.
If I use paginate method it says posts relation is not found in paginate.
I tried this:

`$Posts = Tags::where('name' ,request('tag'))->firstOrFail()->paginate(10)->Posts;`

and this

`$Posts = Tags::where('name' ,request('tag'))->firstOrFail()->Posts->paginate(10);`

Can any one help me to fix this?

Comment: Hi, hosein. Why you try to get a rows from different tables in your `if else` statement? It looks like you need to use `whereHas` method on `Blog` model. Something like this: `Blog::whereHas('tags', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('name', $request->get('tag'));
})->get();` See more here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: @OlegNurutdinov its true men.thank you

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try my code

```
 $Posts = Blog::whereHas('tag', function (Builder $query) {
                    $query->where('name', request('tag'));
                })->paginate(25);
```

you can yse where ha and query builder instans  a relation in models

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Tags has relation relation in model. Also use ->posts instead ->Posts, but anyway:

There is no point of using separate query if relation is defined or not. Instead you need combination of when and whereHas.

```
$posts = Blog::when(request('tag'), function ($q, $tagName) {
      return $q->whereHas('tag', function ($q) use ($tagName) {
         return $q->where('name', $tagName);
      });
   })->paginate(10);
```

1. When fill apply what is inside it if condifion will match. So it is just replace for "if". Docs https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses
2. WhereHas will check if relation model exists and allow you to use "where" (or other queries) on that relation. Docs https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

If you wanna still use "if" nad not "when":

```
$posts = Blog::query();
if (request('tag')) {
   $posts = $posts->whereHas('tag', function ($q) {
      return $q->where('name', request('tag'));
   });
}
$posts = $posts->paginate(10);
```